# Stored Procedure for Updating table from different views

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, sql-update

I have created a table that will combine data from multiple views. So I need to create a stored procedure that will retrieve from the views and update the table. The stored procedure should be able to determine if the record exists or not and to add a new row to the table if the record doesnt exist or to update the record if such a record exists.

Please assist.

Let's use the destination table as Table A and View 1, View 2 and View 3.

**Table 1**:

```
Project_Num(PK)|Region |Area
10001          |Gauteng|Johannesburg
```

**View 1**:

```
ID|Project_Num|Region |Project_Start_Date|Project_End_Date
1 |1001       |Gauteng|2013-07-19        |2014-09-21
2 |1001       |Gauteng|2013-07-27        |2014-10-23
```

This goes on and on in the view where i have multiple project numbers but different start dates and end dates. So I need to group all the project num and select the min start date for the 1001 project number and the max End date. I ran this statement:

```
select 
    Project_Num, region, 
    min(start_date) as Start_Date, 
    max(End_Date) as End Date 
from
    TableA
where
    Project_Num = 1001
```

and the results were:

```
Project_Num|Region |Start_Date|End_Date
1001       |Gauteng|2013-07-19|2014-10-23
```

And it worked. However I dont want to create the columns because I already have a table with columns that need to be populated. Please help with the stored procedure or an insert/update statement and I will create a stored procedure from it. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at MERGE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql And FWIW, the query you posted can't possibly have worked, there is no FROM clause. ;)

Comment: So where you take the region from ? And what about View 2 and 3?? What are their structures ?

Comment: I think you shouldn't create a table, try indexed view: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191432.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396